# detail rows not included query with entity framework 7

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have this query in entity framework 7 that queries a list of invoices, including details rows and customers.
First the data are estracted and after a model class is filled extracting some fields from the invoice, the name of the customer, and the sum of the values from the rows.

```
 var clienti = db.Fatture
     .OrderByDescending(cli => cli.DataFattura).ThenByDescending(cli => cli.NumFattura)
     .Include(cli => cli.Cliente).Include(cli => cli.Righe)
     .Take(recNum)
     .ToList();
 return clienti.Select( cli => new FatturaVm {
     FatturaNo = cli.FatturaNo,
     Cliente = cli.Cliente.Descrizione,
     Data = cli.DataFattura.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
     Importo = cli.Righe.Sum( rg => rg.Importo.Value),
     NumeroDocumento = cli.NumFattura.Value + "/" + cli.Anno.Value
 }).ToList();
```

I found a strange thing: if I add the `OrderByDescending` the invoices are returned with an empty list of the rows, but if I remove the ordering the rows are returned with the details.
Am I missing something?

Comment: Perhaps do the `OrderBy` after the `Include`?

Comment: I tried to place it after and before, same result